# Docker mongodb + node js. How to build working image?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, docker

How can i build this image?

on running image i get

```
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@2.15.5
npm info using node@v4.4.5
npm info prestart koaapp@1.0.0
npm info start koaapp@1.0.0

> koaapp@1.0.0 start /home/pwrchrd/Projects/KOAapp/test
> node server.js

connection error: { [MongoError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND db_1 db_1:27017]
   name: 'MongoError',
   message: 'getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND db_1 db_1:27017' }
```

Comment: check if mongo is on port 27017

Comment: How did you start each container?

Comment: What OS do you use? Could you show us your configuration, Dockerfile, docker-compose.yml?